What type of dynamical systems are discrete sorting algorithms?
Sorting algorithms are discrete-time dynamical systems that make use of logical comparison operations.
(A) In terms of classification of dynamical systems, what is the exact category that these algorithms belong to?
(B) Also as a side question, can we use standard arguments based on real analysis or dynamical system theory (energy/Lyapunov function) to analyze sorting algorithms?

Are you aware of this article ?

It might be useful to write a sorting algorithm explicitly in form of a dynamical system. As an example, consider the standard bubble sort algorithm.
This algorithm can be written as dynamical system by
$$
x(k+1)=f(x(k),k) \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
f_i(x(k), k) = \begin{cases}
x_{i+1}(k)  & x_i(k) > x_{i+1}(k) \land i = j(k)\\
x_{i-1}(k)  & x_{i-1}(k) > x_i(k) \land i = j(k) + 1\\
x_{i}(k) & \text{else}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
j(k)=(n-1) \left(\frac{k}{n-1} - \left\lfloor \frac{k}{n-1} \right\rfloor \right)+1
$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function and $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $n > 1$ (for $n=1$ no sorting is required, as the list contains only one element then). We use the state vector $x$ to directly encode the list with $n$ elements which we want to sort, i.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the list.
Note: Invalid ("out-of-range") indices like $x_0$ or $x_{n+1}$ are automatically avoided in $(2)$ by the $i=j(k)$ and $i=j(k)+1$ conditions, as these cases are never picked when $i$ would be too small/large. If it is desired to avoid these nevertheless, either define $f_1$ and $f_n$ explicitly without the offending case or write $x_{\min(i+1,n)}$ instead of $x_{i+1}$ and $x_{\max(i-1,1)}$ instead of $x_{i-1}$.
The idea here is to use the explicit time dependency to implement the swap operation in a deterministic and well-defined manner. To see that it works take for example
$$
x(0)=\begin{pmatrix}
5\\3\\7\\2\\6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
An example Matlab/Octave implementation could look like this:
% example vector to be sorted
x0 = [5;3;7;2;6];

% iteration of discrete dynamical system
n=length(x0);
x=x0;
X=zeros(n^2+1,n);
X(1,:)=x0;
for k=0:n^2-1
    x_new=x;
    j=(n-1)*(k/(n-1)-floor(k/(n-1)))+1;
    j=round(j); % rounding needed only because of finite precision
    for i=1:n
        if i==j && x(i)>x(i+1)
            x_new(i)=x(i+1);
        elseif i==j+1 && x(i-1)>x(i)
            x_new(i)=x(i-1);
        else
            x_new(i)=x(i);
        end
    end
    x=x_new;
    X(k+2,:)=x; % X-matrix only required for trajectory plotting
end

% plot state trajectories
figure; hold on; grid;
s=cell(n,1);
for i=1:n
    plot(0:n^2,X(:,i));
    s{i}=sprintf('x_{%d}',i);
end
xlabel('k','FontSize',14);
ylabel('x_i','FontSize',14);
legend(s,'FontSize',14);

Note that this is a naive implementation of bubble sort, i.e. without early exit and redundant assignments (could be easily improved, but this is not the point here). This code generates the following figure:

We can see that the sorted state vector (i.e. the equilibrium),
$$
x(9)=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\3\\5\\6\\7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is reached after 9 steps, which is of course the same number of steps as the original (naive) implementation of the bubble sort algorithm requires.
So, looking at $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can see that this system is a

nonlinear,
time-varying (non-autonomous),
$n$-dimensional,
discrete,
dynamical system with discontinuous right-hand side.

Maybe you can find more properties. Also, there might be alternative formulations which might have different properties. But since we wrote bubble sort as a discrete dynamical system, you can in principle, apply standard arguments like Lyapunov theorems to this system.
However, note that $(1)$ doesn't have a single equilibrium but infinitly many (i.e. every $x\in X$ with $X = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|x_r\leq x_{r+1}\}$ and $r\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ is an equilibrium of this system, so this might make Lyapunov based analysis complicated (but not impossible I guess).
Of course, in the classical sense, the system is Lyapunov stable since elements of $x$ are only swapped during the state iteration, so the norm of $x$ remains constant for all $k$. Showing asymptotic stability would be more interesting, but since $\Vert x\Vert$ does not decay over time you would need to show that $x(N)\in X$ eventually for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and some finite $N$, i.e. the invariant set $X$ is reached eventually ($N$ will be a function of $n$, I guess $N(n)=n^2$ should work in this specific case as an upper bound). For bubble sort this is of course a bit lame since we already know that this algorithm works, but if you have some exotic sorting algorithm and you are not sure whether it will always work (i.e. sort correctly and terminate), this might be a possible way.
So whether this representation is useful will depend on the problem that you are trying to solve.
Finally, the properties listed above might change for different sorting algorithms. For example, if you take bogo sort instead of bubble sort, you will end up with a stochastic dynamical system.

Major Categorization is "Arithmetic Dynamical System" , where the modeling involves Integers which gradually move around the State Space.
Alternate Categorization might be "Discrete Dynamical System" , including Cascade & Semi-Cascade Elements.
Observations :
(1) With Dynamical Systems , generally , the state will recur. In the Sorting Scenario , The Original unsorted state will not recur , because the sorted state is the terminal state.
(2) I think there are no Differential Equations involved. We can not use standard techniques , unless we try force fitting.
(3) We might consider some measure of Energy or Entropy or Disorder which will reduce to the minimum. There might be some techniques involved there.
(4) Standard Algorithmic Analysis [ involving theoretical computer science ] might be the better approach here.
Online references :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system

I don't think this is correct. The state of a dynamical system does not need to recur, not every dynamical system has periodic solutions. What about stable systems convering to an equilibrium or unstable systems? Take $x_{k+1}=0.5x_k$ the state wont recur for any $x_0\neq 0$, where $x=0$ is the "terminal" state, yet this is a discrete dynamical system. The sorted/terminal state could just be interpreted as an equilibrium.
